# C# Visual Studio 2013 - Severless databases

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2013

I have a small application that I have created using C# in Visual Studio 2013 which currently uses two SQL local databases to hold numerical values(containing around 50 columns and 50 rows).

I wish to replace these with server-less databases, such as SQLite, however I don't think SQLite is compatible with Visual Studio 2013, therefore can anyone offer advice as to the best alternatives that are compatible, or if there are ways to get SQLite to work with 2013.

Thank you for any advice or help.

Comment: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki#q4

Comment: Thank you for your link Steve, I have now found the download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a C# binding for SQLite, and it is usable in VS2013. I don't recall if it come with a solution or project, but you let VS upgrade or create those for you, and it works fine!

Comment: Thank you for your help John, I have now found the necessary download